# Find Unique constraint on a column using jooq

Tags: jooq

I have a service which consumes the database meta. It consumes the table names and alongwith it the respective column names. Now I can see there is a method called nullable() which can be used to check if the column is nullable or not. Similarly, i want to check if the column allows only unique values or not

Version used: 3.14.15

Comment: Can you please update your question to be specific about what *exactly* it is you want to do with jOOQ? Sanitise your data?

Comment: I have updated the question w.r.t what is exactly required

Comment: Well, you can check values using `SELECT candidate, count(*) FROM t GROUP BY candidate HAVING count(*) > 1`. Is that what you need? I'm sorry, I don't really get your question, and what you're expecting from jOOQ...

Comment: Ok, i will try to break it down. I have a service which consumes the database meta. It consumes the table names and alongwith it the respective column names. Now I can see there is a method called nullable() which can be used to check if the column is nullable or not. Similarly, i want to check if the column allows only unique values or not.

Comment: OK, I guess I got side-tracked by your data example. Does my updated answer help? There's no such thing as a "unique column" in SQL. It's a multi-column constraint, though there are convenience syntaxes to create unique constraints on single columns.

Comment: Is there any other way to check "unique constraints on single columns" apart from traversing through the keys?

Comment: No, because that would be misleading people into thinking there was such a thing as a "unique column"

Answer (score 0):

#### How to read database meta data with jOOQ

The API to use for this kind of schema introspection is [`org.jooq.Meta`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html), which you can access via [`DSLContext.meta()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta()). By default, it is backed by the JDBC `DatabaseMetaData` API, but you can replace that default to work with any of these instead:

- Generated code
- Interpreted DDL
- XML

You can do that by passing a [`MetaProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/MetaProvider.html) to your `Configuration`.

Once you reach a `Table`, do check these methods:

- `Table.getKeys()` (primary keys and unique keys)
- `Table.getUniqueKeys()` (unique keys only)
- `Table.getPrimaryKey()` (primary key only)